# ASP.NET MVC application, shall I use genereated database for all business logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I'm new to MVC web dev. As you know, Visual Studio generated local database to store the user credential, it has the UserProfile table. Shall I create a new database or use the auto generated local database and just create new tables there?

Comment: How can you expect anyone to answer this? The question is far too vague.

Comment: It's up to your requirement. You can use the existing database too.

Comment: Hi James, you get create a web application, then know what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will easier to use the existing database. And you don't even have a requirement to have a separate database.

Comment: Thank you guys. Your answer is important. I accept the suggestion.